# how to convert input byte stream to base 64 string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting below response from server. I am not sure what is the type of response.I think it is input byte stream can I convert this in `base64`

```
����JFIF��(ICC_PROFILEmntrRGB XYZ acsp���-  desc�trXYZdgXYZxbXYZ�rTRC�(gTRC�(bTRC�(wtpt�cprt�<mlucenUSXsRGBXYZ o�8��XYZ b����XYZ $����paraff�
Y�
[XYZ ���-mlucenUS Google Inc. 2016��C


        
%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(��C



(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((���"��   ��B!1AQ"aq2����#B�R���3b�$Cr�%S��������+!1A"Q2aBq��#����?�4�F�;�4���+LB�Ĭ��a9Ui��Ei�D�,1��Q�*�2��6S���*A2
*mBiDi� j�N�E���*$�J    ��@�+S�5S�rRLN2�z��%�L��c�I�^itJS$� �Jd�&1O$�iJT@r��$�1Kd�1HCJI$�6��Bb�i�Q�i����2,bLr�)�� b*.)ʁ��)�;(���#�.,��*�Ў01�6�P�v�9V��ӷ4@r���g  ���I�R��҈T0;)�� Si� 9AM�$�P�( ����B`����O*��!���*���d�)Q�Ӕ�e�*2��d�JTJAE�Ĩ��S��   $�y��R��&%#�Ji����IP�I ��@8H�~I���&�s�Ġ&Jb�)@�TdBED�!�Ϛ����Pq@���Je&�=�蝧(a��q�U�v*a� ��Ӏ��J#NUv�F;䁢�2Q
E�Ab
���L;�a�T��R�2s�%S�B%)�)�&H��9Q����&��) I��H��&)�\�Jt\�#)�*,I8I!��$�'H��PJBS��@e1R���L�E)�H���RQ!6�$�<� ��C��I�9P��LC�C��g�0�eR���T�L�q�W�[`���>���(���R�F�)�<��eH�$P�4�҂H��
�Ҋґ4Xiʘ(
(���f�9�J�(��N�aH0r�\�@�N'@ItO�e���[e!��Ha!�I�`:\����IrM9H��tИ��$LJrSBm�R��#)B�]$�1����(��q�    ���'��N>�@�����;�>e@�s�̪��  �,`��*���3��j��HI�y����J���{��`�<Ot�Y����5�c��R�s<ֶ���Y�n�|����=U�#&���DX`�f�UV�Zg���@�8N�
�w��m��)�Ҋ�
*m>i"�QJJ((`Q���`�
*m@D�L
Tp�T��N�D:d�C?$� Btp�2I�N�4З$�uHM��k��2��#�G�"S��®n^�r���0�Mwn���J@Z�!��*~��~��ǽ��I�X�Y��O�l{���w{�c=L�AK�w%ͪI�s�L(Ӝ����X�  @�!�{�"ҌT
�w*< "&! HD����@Y�e�z�Y���B�\�Ը�����%~�rك^�)���EZ�V�cj0�p��
E��%����2c�]�$@p�
 9�O��=���#J�Ôf�A�QPQAH�`��ZQP�QJ+P0�*j
S   X�
P��,��d��1BG4�\�,���0��H=p)�W}Q��O�B�빲�Tx��P�������ԯ]��Z�G��H]�K��ʯ��芠N�/�J�����P��H��=��
����t��`��%C kWp��c=L�9�_�ew&�G��Jp�9 
�=�K�����@E�    XHp��O��L���L7N�    4'K�D��3��@QpSQ((��S���� �p�J�������i�'p���?<,�I�9��N�l����#9����T��]B��Z�3J�.)`$�+�e\\PmF�w�=�RJhX��x�E��Ei�]�Q�Q���mrJ#L ��1ʫNQZP4�Mr+�U�~�),4�4�5�a���Š҂A��  �M� '����RHn�$�ćY�lsO54�&3>-��h�h�\�t��0O�D��6�[Y�d��r˜`�#�g���Ը$��< �v@��B�H���@l� �8J�%>�a2BH%�KnH���&���<�LS�Lw@ȕ�T��u�?5��*$��ݺC9����x<����0�:눣M��:~_�
�[0����s����I��p�
��]�w��P��=�P�k��9��Q�*����aC����~�u�=�D&Q��V�w��p���>�tAQ�\]2x�$Xi��p���҈@isDb�
w�Q�eUi�Ð�E�f�aVaGaH�ò3Uv�f�1�iSn�M(�Dap���$�TS���$� I?$��R�!���.i 9M)$�RL��'9L�C���0��@Q)���JG꘤%@�(��IQ)�J�@���20��e8Z��:c�g�7��U�Q�z�X�0>��sNA[�)L�vI?ف�u'���W������eO
�b$�W�IW��>���xeq�k�����B��xsAA�+����-u��-��͏�3�sT��'t��3��n��g+!�"4���ҁ�iFa®ӔV
�d#�ʪŽ‘b,��*�
+
Xn�AiEiHaZ��QHhp�2p���$�:@"�2A8J>ID���<�cz%�$Ӕ�q�b��I���$p�L�yJS%(��NS C木���"�S��JnJ�NP�85�q�%mќ�7:�6u_����e�7�G�?5���;�J����:�����@��¿4�&�åĲ��,��D7    0%�`�@�G�}A�8d�n�ǚ5YQ��ӄg�O�•X'\�{J���ڌ8;�h��.M��L�z�+L�b�
��i�{��!�p�ҀӐ�ӅQxf�f��]��&4Za�GaUi�ze"�ZaFiU�Q�P�QZUvV�A�T�P�D0r�D�\ӂ�$��%�<�I�$�O*<Ҕ钔Ҁ�M�$�t�'@$�H�$ĠJb�Q@ ��D��D����$ dy*���,��+%su�œ��)�W$U�[`��7�b���Y��e�wvm�_rG(P��?�[���0���:�ՙoN�6�I/;��̷d�U��ǁI�F��8�y'x�+�q   ��q��q7�u|i}v��8E�A�䁲��9i�Z�נ�{�b��.Jֻ��U���(���i��S���FaU(UmZm{��Q�`n�4v�O�Xk���*�(�)E�a�Ta�Q锉��
3����"E��f�Y�FiI�E��@P|�e"AD)���aML� ��L�t�LP1$�d�t�JH$�d�yIE<�H&����ĠJ�R�@��R*?�%�J�@~ˍ����T���.��E��jq\������ۉ��-���Iї<�aq{Ed.h��&g�gc�!v4K��Y�w�u1�B�� (��4e�B�R�KI�T�>s#�U�����j�<��<KH�+���"A�b/59I��qc��T����d�+$ ���l�2��u��ü����]����Z��2
���B�ݯ�[8y���_$t�Y�l~�
(䫱ȭ�g:�Œ�tUXQ�r�X�l(�8UQ�R&�l(�*�Q��E��V�]�(�8QpT�BiS�@T�)�@ɧ�S�@:I��@vQ%)H c�b�R��t�&@�99Q����J@����E)@�9LJJ$�"y&�19Q��rT\SeD�q���n⾪|�i�r�U�jV����NV�2峛�/�[�Zܶ��#�^֮[ut�S2���~���Q@���n9�,�7��3ny�A�F�9"��z���V�����X�N�D;�pB9��EW�8���L]�n2�<C��]]��'�*ƕu�k�ן�~���� �Q�Lp�����i����r4���ۅ����9�c��|����㚜T�lfUZQZ�P.E�8��ܕF9��D�q��U�v E�"���(�*#,4��҈
'P8)$��JP"r�*�P2R�Te4��)P.E�D��e$��3��O�L��P.M8�')J�rbP MĆJ�z�FP��*��+Z3�W��9L����}��d�]�D�q+��͞�ySѱ�T+����m�:�U�߃4��!��@3�΅���߼��`�օN��wW+� ��b�I�f��c]&m��N�˞֞���q���{�|\D���6�EFI9�8��h���{甆�L����znĕa���Re  �>GX�P�yy��^�d�V%�"��!8"%�z����G��?��T���F�!$&$�ty!��ϒ��($=�ɶ�mM�p��,ppe�x��_D��h<����,��j���f���;�w�+]
�\��ac:����Fc�&�dv�&M2��1ʍ7+,rD�.1��*���J�2�L"�5ȭr�Ĝ8$0�Ia�CA$���v��4t�62�'T�a�=$��:�7���_>��u����l�i�߲�;�hOݩ?�s��Oc#��P�ml��j����V]��icQ����i��� ��{O}����T�9}��&
����j�퍓�_Oy������bҫxM#I���?Pp�1�2|I��v�6�ng�\�F����n�WV�;4��~���Ǵ[=K����7f�Y�'r+�b��;+��!� �����q���[j
q���@s'-�w�|��v�T�oi��]��X8d�t#���{G�|��Ԫԧ8.k�?�Ź�W�4��1�ܫ^��V�6z�*5��
_�]P�cIX
�qI�)�=�؃!q�GI,�d�L��)���`P�s�W�&�^��L<S,4�����1���r���n���Z�?��A��(�̦�ʵ$�397���R�'��R��4b]�S�ጠv    �D�N��;���ǒ��X�Q��|�#|��Dʲ�[���u�@�Q�����A�np�h�>,��Uu�G��荃p������
9���P*!�0���Cxܝ��
��1�O�:�y���w`�
�:�V�a�҈�h5MY$�٨����[Q�%e��Y��ҩܸ�dy�c�������L�f?�S��5��Uѥ2��1�es�S�3�Th�gM�6GeEͧQXeD��gA�Fk�>r���4Dժ���M�7$�gC��q�A�;]�ơuJܩ�'��*ڏhl�Rwt�թ���x�i�J�w5뺵F(
��s�Oc]�f���/v����jQ��
N1tabnnj<Ip�E՚N�v8��q*�g��\g�R*�˦%K�S�㸟D7�=��@�N�e3�9J'�(�AD��(Q.2�OUAEL�Jq;�_�)!X����T�UqS��H�`��Th4n�\酂ޫ�e�ݖ;�7����ը�v�~#�x���ZF���U�����
�W�I����@�>)���k��&��Fq�?�]_�nM3�N..���$D��'��2��   #�D`�Q��@��Lco�g=�8"TEI>�����"c"ݱR-�ᆀ<ʉ��8|`Ƕ�(���k��H ����(S�x����_MwyTA�����/�P~
�"0���>(dtԗB�dL�P#8D<�T��:J��d(��(
��Bk�@�j��*�@A���'������A"����w���^�.>6�˃R�ѹ�mT��dAW��i�g���F��G�D�`,�Ԯ^qS��'U�T�c���U+N�f�k�F�״i�f���V{����,���4eMi��^�?�!�*T~.r�����m1���5�kr:#5�ņ��Z���E�����qT�.(C�I��4c�JxZH���%�C���vW��i�$���Mם\�Up%�H$�{�n5':���W<\!�@���|���W���I��I��s�J�z}7)2�鶋Z��峕J�y���*�R ���H��*���NNg� Ձ�+���Pq�U3`���T\�$��r̨�����Qu���/q�g,��搦I�]FY�c�Y���)<�k8���$��y�-%;#
��h@Py��E���7u�u�H�R���`eJ9o�2��Fu�H�peJ���\Ua ¹;��(�ֲ��mY����KL��;c�[֦˧��dd|y�#q�j�O|U��O�>\0ȪH�K;���mk~'5�AY
�N�c�qZ��������e���Ǭ.��g�Ϗ���7r�Ԏx�\�����J�`�۞����s��,�%��@O›�����'��G�{>��
��S���mjw5���Pp�&R�3�A��+�<�@���0w�!;����L|>
f=aE�0�`�6�(����%E������C"A�ب�4
O��v*�Y����H->�@�TW�*�����L,fF��F�M�h�Т����ȓ`!�ʋGP�ф�#c������\!�D��ƒz�ڽ~*��K����*�KlM�^�T���;B���bk?�=�Ǔy��]w�jq]�{�|��k�oj�f���U�E�>���\;��U</5Q��g����2�������T����\�6
����o
��  cL�������ia���3;���Ӫ�#˙ٚT��U��i3�l7�z-�����]Sd��⑇��4����N��$��^<�=�{����[H�Ł�h0�-@}HR�$��9�VA��P���_��-�^���d\Je�9!=�2����歉T�e���L��Y��w1��V��l��[5�@ʾ�,���s�Ԛp>��������zfYF��g���M�}?=�    �/Y���k�[�n�7v;v�`�*��Z����Z�s�:�W����2��=��9R?OE��εOV�m@HxÁ��1�ښ|��Nk�NUS'p�#�S   %̧�$M"b@;�w�9��"y!��uA�k>�V�i�Ӹ*��8�z�k�:�F���?��?��ʳ\�C�;�h�HlegcP�1��2z)��1�B9�3���'y` v@�d�y�D;!�� �`߱�V� �
�Em��6U�    �   ʕ��Qjv(t: �aZ�#���*mk���E�b#\6$ 5��$�����f�LAU�uDc��u��du���>0A`�j�h�*�j��S6����{�8H<   #����A{*q��!j5�WI�KiQ��F0'}�-K��G�̦`�#ch��
˚L��LO>��깺E�]_\�J�9uJ�6�eV����  
��5��O�{�ȯ�?T��m����9%�6wqG|��{Oa�3OIѩQ�oy�.>k�}f��``B�Z��p�J��O4�A�+�J�FZ�`k[$�X��W5Q5����c�Ϫ�j���ō1���]���p\�ar�NI�-�w�3�p�S�c�DYA��H�!t�X��aU��|B���1�Uw���5s!U�K��E$FEz��PB��2v@}9��)�+��8xQ���D�L���yn�c+3uK����:�����m�
�K��,|�jn�Bb�$e��+���vGUn��T�
���^�n��M3�çp�{c�������q�<�:��3��Z{^�M�L��Trc�Q��V��V<�|R=OE �O��� �����
?t�;n�����R$�|o��v׳B鏾�g�5�:�5���#�T��F�EIS<�KI����J���XV�/��x�ꔇ?1���
��0䃃yB��"���1�" ��d20�ᰏ��!!�_�<��}�2�p���7
�]�H�dZ��S�Rh�F���"�Ԁ�#r��tB�"���j�d&��I�s������
�$y.'m�Ym�:ޟy^��L�����6d]��- a�8Y>��:��X��w,i��?`�ڇ���\kOkɔ���X�g���@_W�$���{7@I��i�n��*pNu�c��4\���Ǒ_[X��:��^&�q���L������ }cQ��0pY�l�RVq��qki�.
����_Ti7/�2�Ջ]>�%p�ۚfI��T7e�^�ÈF�r.�o3+�r��� ���0'`�� ��(��D���s�S}f�����h�*��A*�9�Uj�a�W6��0I�)EY:!X���
�
������6|�*��Y�;Dq6d�Tw��4g���C����_Wr
�f��jH'��+}�E+#l҆�ꆩm��p�����V�x���'�#Ϫ
��yKb<��r��t�U=�#��h�%N�i�.�f���괪�`���pB3T���VH�EşA�{_I��tD'�}���u�R�[��cp����h�����ڳ�d���Y ��D���L��%EΏ2��=�n)ʋg��h�Y^���<q4� ��Y����+˽����$i��ɲy�<��?�z5V�j���RvADuY�#�����جm�7���<;զ�^al�X`�����W'\�,⚦x�����-�ltF��l;�����|ǒ�8@�W�Y�Qqt�;@P;y"�H;aA�G4   ߓ����(/�@�V��t8�-N�c}�HL�|��0���*#b-���V��,*�<6��(̪֌�@�W�c�E6��!�ㄘ���(��
��i�"�
��F�}Y��� ���Mkm^��2s2v�%[Mm:���q�� t<9�����l�Z���:���5���3���侹��1KE�`����s�
4�������}u�S�l-��
6���#T�Ć�I���8����kv��=��`y�@�]�YT���s  ������egS�i>����UI�M-D����*]�s��N�'��U�Kf'��j�e���7�q2�O��L�p�*�!�[�'ѵ��~!���G8*n�Q�D�ve�0�%���w����"Hӎ�e��N%sn����V��{�8�dB�k�D��)�9���'qu+�&�j��-�긗%�j�k�.IqE
�s�0�J���T(��l��P����W9�4Re5X�M���~�
�?�"��KN>FR�^IӢ��%Ӥ�A�y�;j:��[+�.6�T��%�x9ݡ��^Z�,v`�[˦�����]�4n^�"
�3e�6Cc��#s�j��Zd������Ψ~�R�些�m�n$,�d��I�Y�V�\|���j���TO-�i�m�ɉ�(��J�$�"�':?���%
���2��2�U�-�'�����H����=?گa���:���q�� ��������f��T��k;��>_e�7���n���&=�{�8����w����^�����p��,�c�s1�w���6(�'��1��#v�AՌ̮���Ӿ�OH��Vm�;c���Z˻oX�6�l��]2�^�p��,gj4[q]Z����?A�K|�1d#�M��1���W'\�J
J��Nn�(OE��wg��76�εy��OE�xV�f9E��+�9J������2eC�6Dx��O5$FD�%Xh1�I�J�Fd@��C�p��6�Y�l�ttOv֖Rk�� 
�`���e˰ًwd�!]��Z��PWdw�0z!6�J��-Oiq
 �����N˚3uL5R�L���-�o��ޏS��ܾ�89�?x
�:�n���0��y�RyK��3��`�t��.���*3���Y�?�=�V��-;P���l���q��q�+��ց��7_{]�s��_V:�����wl�o��S���#�������`�H�������:���
\ L=�j����YP�;�&�d��c������'���q��΋k
�O��EmNޭ@��?�A��}U�Ǆ:z��������u^��#����-GS�U�,�,�H��qɟ5�Я�ʝVf���5��U���b8y'�q!�-3��&�:�����%a;]k�r���˻çޘ<�+���SU��r��c��<�[wwo��Yw��-��h\�p�ujneB����h�渲͵�(89�#�=mn�<=ۋ��cA��>�x:J��j+\w���'v|T�M�V�$�"�\q�~*�M�>:d�+��g����v�Օ�<7)��ki���N�+NE�]Q�����=0��Q��m���BI&���k��K9�kCN����tpp��Sm�ӜE�գݕ�'���]�?D*�4�9�v�)��kJfI#�;-�2��J���淙��֟���E���Hg%�e�<%iY�Qʞ������+���G�U*��|�=�y\�W��B�t3���6J:x��y���J�H�|�:��I�^��6������ㅾ��Hq\�N|���_=�l��_l��[B�i�,I����� P�'��3�_.v���=���t���Ux�&��G&��}Zƶ�iF������h�&b~Ez/���ҽ�OHת��7.�5��[eZQgd�+44:櫇���0 �������j6Nִ`NK�۰A�'���RYjTʲ`S����RҬ8K:�;!`=����;@�h����3��}����-�Rp�F�uZ�#����J�w_J�C��Ai漯�}�~�r^��ZT2��^�ׂ$P��F���+�>��U�ўpR��ʣ;�T6Zn�hut��K�ݖ>>��g*��R�N�r[]2�ǋ��&`�1�Q<[*�aX�4�<�j�n7�MJ�8V�G0���)��:�$���+��ZU��X�����M>��`*wvt�۲x�Z|Y�X�Mų���    �)�6ҝ
T�6��q1�?C�U�7���s[Z[�|-hp3�IV*�mk{��$����r5的6�������*M����+J-�S�{�
.���d�����+�n�5�����%�5h���q�^\9�LOWO�ycLգ���]��}�ѧu��V��|� >n`E��#N�ZL�^-��澹[�!��= w�^Ѭ<�p �.Nl���0(��{K��a��v���:W�YS�֣�mH���8����������:T�q��[��R�5Zc��$LsT¢��$�ӣ�;wg�S�r{�ܹ��iUik�N�N`B�G[��tѱs����M�}�k�P���w�,m^��=�)��~��EDg�s� �Tu*T��kDܭf���{j~*�c?���'R�P�/y0J�/g���j�3�\c�<��'I|�t;١�v|�%�I�}��i\T�ܯz�mB�2��k��kk�-��U�4v�iœ�M�?�<�W�����W���Ә �
�r�>En����L�f͵Gl����ַ�v�    � e[�4Q��g^}֟5f��@A+��<9��N�I�'���G��&\����v{��J��ɿ��pH����*�Z �5P���l�L�H�v�߻���`��kL�Z�^߿�x#!e���,�%�;���MԞ5��l��D��K���
�t�C7_�<��*@�9�h�8��N"y��P�U=U
�ɨ�O�^���j���.ȑ�bgK��9�RW��_��7d�Hz���2e�}���h��x���@d�0�6a�g�-��;-mh�5)��7y�ܫz������a��\& +7Y4Y�U���)UUh��.��©�&x״�g������:��Ԡ��tD���Y�����in��#h^�z��^K�Z��V䓻\7��/(���Z�����3Q5H�
\��c#ꧏ#����c�Qֺ�h�ՠEKw�&��aV�2!y�b�aq�˧h��*.׏�yy/L�e��eŋ�Zޠ�c�d��Vq3cx�%K�4/�B�4������t��M�*N��5鵩�4��y�:����u�KH��P�N��JG�Tl;#�+��I+��5{K�Q{Ih�w"�[>uc�3m�1�7+]�`�Q��@<'iPsH��| :�QN�م��q ��@�m8EYs�CJ��Q�V�vǽ�I.��#k�0��k@��c˒̒:�heQ��9�ԫӊ��H2�h��_P������^��^3�o�]����Vl���w��1�E��zg��->]j{i$dmHk�|'쪺��hլ湽��:���δ���sj�5��>��
.�N�O��Th"������S�1f{R:ONzw��k���Jժ�Y�����F���q�`Ú20���m�o��z��l@O�m�-{�d��(d7��;g�^���=��.h�<��Z�Ë�����^��io?�ݒ�   �;|eb5�-��8�CI�N�҄���'r�p   p?��G�p�䫗v�\����23�ZR��A���ͧ͢_A�e77'az�e��m� ��d��Vw���~%���YA��`4�c9����d��g��
�7��i��=�������Z#;��g�/�Z�{�TN~�?��+FUk�H�  ����).�������'�k6�E���J����������#�f�+*%��q�G'������d��o�!���   DX�O$�$��T�!�bUΙO%���l˜��   ��i<p��V���R�b*U x�����ݸ�u�V�9¥p����+��j�a(E��# ��d��%�uZ(lxk閞�ql[}R��l���WQ��jߘa���[U)M&s�-�[��ă�!�z��*��-���m��X�K�r�6d�M�.� 'jm�ԛ�)��;%J����]`aWi�7!\�#��nn����+�@pƚ�z�����ڶ�#�oI������;Pm�j�M�T�iX���ؕ�P�n�ܶ�?S�)�k�zQ�]��$�N>�Hf��������겥��k�{GA�%�MGr.��������^v.'�#�U�R㷷�8� ���*����t�!�L%�$���(<��G`�kͺ�eG6��0�U,��:�W��"�5+mZ�J5��t���d����U�;?���(� �6>�xW��^��[�"xX���O������_^�~M���T�!���Ⳟ0��[�]5@��rH�V�G�vV��"K��T vF��
L�d!�&�v6�OtIiYV_S����Caŀ������2���2���\ח�ڑ�:�&@'����m���Ġ�����Ju(�@���27�R�O��<'#iV�K
��j�r�d�A�l�N��K�{�L�>�3�ᓄ[3��uP75@��K��V���.�y��^gٸ��i�k����W4�^��ӊ��DF��%�B��ޗ���-R�*�]ް<�"hWL����`kEVx9� �H�������q.����6�I5]J.+����4�#�
:xԎ�<o+�k��^�9s.�z�-��}�ܹ�M�����5[&g$G�)o}�2E�M2��d��ac5{0\Z��"I��|���H4T/;m;n��E�iӣε-<S���A��j\4��0g[�]6�]��^���f$�N)+]_��"~�l�-B�m�Rۂ�����&W��/�\5�ԭgk�E�_hT�n�w�`<�����ã�-;Se�SiG    v\VK�6��I���$f6_?С�j�E�5�燼"}�����K�R��ԉmW�c��S�\�Y\j2�D����Xms[j�1�����]��V�~0����Lz,��Хp��2    ��Y��N�-tJ�in�{�o�˧V��X�)�'�\��;�d*lv8�%{��
VG\�m>�[P�]�5��$�,�<D��
�4I�U8���ΕW�1�T�x���6�w��L�(�A.J����L=��0$�ЌNy���{�tn���{υˣp�xp��ξ��
&@�+E2��5jN���IF�%�j���(-8Dn�Ĩ�&�,;Q�\O$V�g�z��WT�-2�^���[�F���Z����1��*��%{�d��7N��Ӳ�F�kK+��$s�c�<��E�\�f�-���چ^׌�I��Ӛk8=���   w�*�Q�.hĈ
7mN-.�c���TL�L�E�l�ɘ&�GG ���A�M�����Y-%�����)�x3�}1�!  ��h����V`��?�p�k���T{-�?���[����-�������O��YO��/-�>��齟�h[Q����=��-�G��`F
o0�Qp����*�鴜 Q��L��j�|��8R�R�   �*tiI�Z-��
tX
VFr�'I�1W$���{�=�ń��5��t�>�����$��s^�iq/ԩq��|������yl=��|�6oj)�h��:��:,k��8��0�����]�)��v6ۋ^8�i�^k�u�F�y�L��aX�mD�es��yoe��c{��^��Rv�qN�<.�O����ը6�>��MA��-����c��b�\'e+�*C��Ӹ��f����[>��6����pu�ЧR�T���ҩ���9+����{�\:�d�������r���{�<�
�[?�}I��Z�l�;V�a'�  ��qx��R��^�:����[���d�q�    ��d��c��    �'?'��.��=Pi�'ŷ.��h+�
d5�#�a�G\��I��U^YTK4ѹY�����V#Q���&J�kć8���4�V��]��cJ��n�al��.>�W��b�����.B�{�a� ��j]�m�&6��N$q@ z�c��Sȼ�K�_C�*ӻ��P5K�\�D<n�˷]�ԵZϬ�t鸵������O_���Z�[���
sfK���5Ǹ��V��M�2&9���L������z���>y�ɸg|���d�T�ep���6*ŵ��������c�K�.��L���mD�S1�{�"xH�%B��霂��+�'u�ԝ��
2�v2
�:�l��hk+5�.I�U��n��Y[�4/��[WmJb�R��%��d�����(5�}�t;����רC�B���s)�7y�W��Ç�s��N�WG����w�!��(0�_�YW�M�m(
�Ea™��a�+$D }/ًv�kv4�6X����+�ׁ��ߤ��&�^�[e;x�w���y���mӭ�i���^�-g��t�>K�\�O�M�q�����NsTy���f^��O�H�sV��
��u@�Q��we�i�ϓ�u���_R�ckF���D5�a���o��%���#���F�m��2��G��e���P�ӯkӸ��2ӉH?(]OoՍ]cJ��_���k��Ņ��q�Pc>Mk¸G7[&�U
<S`�R��y��4�dl%A��+j8�eaN�"�4���tW6w�" ct��h�$�5'�&�L�=V]ݕ����k=�/yyx�g`�W�a���Vu�WW!���铏������mq�����Z{��h5��.'ԕSZ�mōz�GKrT͓H�ˈ�Tj���G�q�r�ɓ�r�QIN}�^��p2��+G��5�>���p��3T��9��5����*���k;o
�}c���X�
�u1?�k#��e��&�X_W�m�Z�Y^��Pn`��^�ٻ��hV����OY��ey�j\M���%��~�
�k^a�Llgb'����S7#��:��=ݚ�O����?\�*��{ˤoJ��
w�Ϛ�|�R�t̍���+#g�ƒ��kmuĴ��F9������P�}˚�ח�luV����E��{;�S{�Z��7   ��~�D��6,�i��R滉���>�c��^��  �Ts����>���[���Umx=�d~��-?":��ոh��� ��'�[�E793U�P���mF�5<1���W�zn%���1$�4�ǩYZ��i��V�5�mK��%�qo���'ɪ2QT�;յT��    ����y<X�6R�ixG�@�%T}���(ME������k1��|T��+6K��6A�bXH ��e�h�qI�RҪ���z��a.�—Eo�-�]m9��e�pa[��i:<�\�\3�ڎ����2=B��7�����*Qkd�ih#eR�ߕ��XDeR�q'
ؕ�L�
�Q�3Ǆ�Ӧ_%q)���&�F6���@�E�e��>��Ai��#`�c��zXܬ��;_��i�"
W�|9-`P��]������i����P_p�n����q9$�
uɧl�x�a�g�C#A�m
F�<�"�/o�\�.��ɾ�����l��D>A<3����B��dF�z�u��A�����>ۘ��;��e�׿2�����/��־?�Ŭ�Î�Mi�l�TfN�E9�alG!�-����#!��ʉo�T�0�T;�#��3Z<Ҡ����A{3�=�j0ĩe727�As2D�[��hnn0�P���%["P�؜�*$�Y̑�*�UjYj=�d�����etDL.^�A�h������
�6h�<yS4�⥸k���1�B�|N� �I9\
2����Ag�ԏH#�tx�����&X�����j�ڭ   sLxY$���M��z���2�#ZD�]���/.�%�:��;�iK
�   q��U�핖����Zi�p�#�ʕ������d�޼�.^���u����bH��YVc�&��{ k9��y-֗�
@�2��w��ӷ(Q��+�ik^\؈��ݾ�8��s�GcoN��3�Vvݔ齤�'�u�Tl�����WW�A�aM ���v�k�N>
�Ï%V��M�$�1r��)�E��c���IA�l܀��yn�\xr��6��qnXd   S��#j�\�bUF�M�S쯦t�'�e��07PmV��NT^�2�I��-���:�]����c=
�_sS\�H�`�0T���TN�����c�"
v�)T
-����:§O��Ӓ�0AR*?G4qk�YR��  ����BR5��
5�|�'*��+R�mۉu�.q2 ����W*d4u#�����oX�n�/���U��z����$G�a�����sN��z<,�#�q�;�d��
y���5j�w{���g���꙼w�����v�V���.'���o�>kv/��k_���d��$b��H�ĭi��Q��(Nn��?�V���dYY��NL�60���$ ��9V���t
��d�A�Ȍa[p��q;����`<��=��%m�̠�$&+*���X  �U����"y�J��L��]���������B?�+5j��iwnqg�����:o4m��sX�u�#U��H7�Įf�y^�"ۚE��{�8�9�s��E��b��]���Q�u*�q�9=Y
n�'�����e�u�v�p3�1<�9eq���i>�`�n܌���`�L�)�f�,w斑�guش�)�5Ѵ���R�k�S�a��;�E6��&p:?��o�h��tB��dA����jUH{�N�Wf��{�1�ٟ?EZ�G�X�����

<�n��_��)�er.)�q�%z%m��
�{U��`y��ai��F\��L�6�\���|~���@�T�HIo���)2������`9�����w
���栗$��Q�.��r��x�#�?�#��$�\H �%aSd�A#��c�/�>)��T�VN��v�7���ju S��`$K�K�
�C�
4�s�NE  Á��c��\�_.�x��QP�*p~
sG�F����2�fc��B�Fp;,>��:$��m@�:D��9��t����)�5�T��>Ix�����+��W���*�YK�9]�xXL�d�6���F�g����5L��A��ܼ�5�H���ea�Ct�b����� O'��W?�
��j�����?b�UGS����&����7Ý�]��9�B��U�3���2�VH*��z��vܩ&&���1ܩ�@�L��YA�0���F�n�2���F��4Ē���$7�L�R��B���G{fa�1�dY]�d��5r���*�Lu��v��gu��i��ccIͩ�i��TW�8�Rs3���o��rZ�N�I�W���4�?��A���#M~�[��    �I�ޤ��XOͥW8)Zf��a�f�:����jV��Hs˱2"G�s�֮��3��8��Eß���,ߤ6�.��!��>+?p�U�q{����%rrc�鞯e�
q,Z��"�A���>X�
ݭ:-�{����ѻi��9��O�s��]VT5hS���D9�s;�
�B�/���ѭJ�PkS%��g���V]\2֩{������f��jKL��v�9�'߻��k`���r�J��$���c(Tw��$
��b�*Ĺ̫�`O�_�M���p���pkW.3�1=Q+���[\1��j���Tn�����䫶��F3
��ʕlM��uێaF�n&�����fAQ��p?T腖 ��j�������&: ��P��#��Q閐C�iF0��7r��a�p��vE���\=��+}.�fT�V�y��
v[��P92\%���G5Zf��S��N��
Lt��%N�E-n��S�!A��tV�%r~�����yC��(����$퀊��a\�}>7T��NL9�1�?��1���۳��.Jd�4�-p��   8KKy�}�9��4L��n����1�a�I�\<C��K̽��x4�a��#��+���E�:_��}��b���7��#=靕�&��'�҈-��#τ�1�O&>V�g]���"[�E<R�8�/����s+�    ¯Y�<�+�$*�(%X�V��[��qc��C@  ��a�$���s@����M0er��.h�i�ۧ46��dJ���
à*�n6�A��a4&U�3���x����I����2%gp��q�궇j�������k���{b?�Y��e^�U�,��:�D|e؞���Gf�@��K�;Pi���sC�`���D�1�fn{3t�W/��;�7���$�?뽝���niÞ>"?u��M���mR���c��c��su�d���>���q��Ew
��S��>!�sG�}Q���xC���&~ej����h���[Q�WOq�����9�r�y��k�T�!ĳ�o��'�MII\]kW�i6��gbv��\ZwO]�]��>�S�5)T����3r�w/4��H�n �̥����YpYVC�����f�  �r�'��`���<�5U�%���*#e�TK�s��z���P�4!��T;
"�(�@�!��3�'d�oI͌��8�B,     -g�+VTL��hP��O�+��
-�&������7��'�rX��+tL���B�+�g
$��GT{��B��#� ��ʅ���    ;I)'�
o@LFS��Q��29#����WE�2N4��-I$�@I$�K�����Oj�-�Ki5�g�^мO�n���J��\Ӧ}�������$zƢ�ѳ�O1���.���]Md�Z�d.cD4Bы�8���kC�(Db
�v�9¹FvA��}U� �U�Ϣi�`F��Z"R(�`tRlE|�T��a�~�nM12�����i�PH�Eb �A���g��'˒��h�*���쭖���R#eW7��\�mZ5)U�x!��^-�d!=�rQD�i�8����]V��r��ZUa����xO�c�:�T֘{�6�z���u�ZԮ-5;q��<=���l��|��k=^�Y�h�Y:iUl�݇g4� �r�˕g��f�e(�1�:u�Q��O'rߪ���:��>��uĈsZ��?U����Uŭ
y̅���p�p���ۋ��4��<��f�,+���w�헗4��c|��d+�w�.d>�W8��2}W�������Χ�Z�Rx,l�VG?�T�.��7��sOɐfLr#uY�䱰�V��F��8���Cr���'�\q�[�'�W���4�fz��bd�W*Rp��@��)�#��Q�t�ų��
�̩� X�:'�U�lkyS��T�\���> 0z)�]䙴�E�1 6�$v�"�1���J�mz|lW*������؜�]Jf��z{˛f��.X[J�c������ש�S~XxO�U�gV��GP�E����j   V��ݟ�X���\�����Ѷv���쾫iH֫iS��$f9+b�3�d�?C�I$�$�I"�G����C_v��*ϣI���]R���˺��t��+�=����W{p��E��\?��E�>^gz���x�U�gS%�1� 
+D8�8z��i2�2BЊD7l�$+S2�Fp��?�8  ��J,(��D�)��'r�F0�dZ�#d#���;E�D�*I��>�H䬻 �8䓅4�0<89�
ۍ����   ۉ���� �v�����3��}���b�%��Q�@���(~}w��˩�%��ߤ��گ�q�[�����p��˓�ө��Z��d�T����9n�=���>����(Q�N�Jt��}*��� ��ɝ���봺8i`�����JWT[^���O�s��g�����c$�>�����ɩ��|��&����<�}Wf�{�A�,s\%�f|�f��Z�g�^�xB�������  �--�tc�����.�FR�D��{�8<�f��&�s�¶�9
�W2�xp�Ԥ���z%jr{�~�Vƣq��z
���3�\k�F�;
��e2ļZ�)��o��ճ��ϧ%]֧���h��@�p���n"xL���@�|;'�   @�MJ<�h"p�<�ky�A���m�W��$��
�?�z�D_!.��4��!��o��A�[jE��Ws|���\�v�:��A���
��3E�^K�<�j�y��O�h�ڶ��
```

After getting I tried to convert this in `base64` string to show image.I do like this
`btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(image)))`

`image` variable is equal to server  `string`

```
77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAAABAAEAAO+/ve+/vQIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA77+977+9AAEAAAAA77+9LQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlkZXNjAAAA77+9A**
```

but when I am trying to render the image it is not render why ?

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/dopakuguhu/1/edit?html,output

I tried to render like this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

could you please tell me how I will render this image ? something I am missing could you please suggest a solution

any update?

Comment: The JFIF part of your byte stream makes me think it's a JPEG, not a PNG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)

Comment: may be JPEG..!!

Comment: But if your server is returning a JPEG image, are you sure you can't just use `<img src="point-to-your-server-here" >` ?

Comment: but server is returning `input byte stream`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Yes, but that's normal for the plain old `<img src="point-to-your-server-here" >` case.  The point-to-your-server-here part is the url to the image on your server.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "returning".  Is there some reason you can't treat it like a normal image?  How did you request the image that the server is returning?

Comment: actually server is sending in `byte` intead of base64

Comment: @user2740650 server is sending me `input stream` see some above question `some` special charaters

Comment: @user2740650 i don't have any `image url` which i put in `img src tag`

Comment: Can you modify the code at https://jsbin.com/dopakuguhu/1/edit?html,output to fully show the problem?  The output there starts with hard-coded output that's not working.  Try including some script that hard-codes the response from the server (the same as in your question here) and converts it to an image and demonstrates the problem.